# What Editions of RDP Host allow users to use RemoteFX USB Redirection

Tags: windows, usb, remote-desktop

I have been trying to find documentation on what versions of Windows have support for RemoteFX USB Redirection. After some investigation, it appears that versions of windows with RDP 8.1 and higher have support for RemoteFX, but only Enterprise Editions and higher of Windows can be the Host of the session if I want to use the RemoteFX USB Redirection functionality.

**Is there a Definitive list of what versions and editions of Windows can Serve as a host for RDP sessions that can use RemoteFX USB Redirection?** I have found a few links for older versions of windows that specified that only Enterprise editions could be used, but the list of supported Versions stops at Server 2008 R2 with SP1, so I believe the list is out of date

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817578(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: You do realize that RemoteFX was discontinued right?

Comment: I was unaware that RemoteFX functionality for RDP was discontinued. I did some quick googling and I wasn't able to find any information on that. Do you mean RDP is being deprecated going forward or just that RemoteFX functionality will not be supported going forward?

Comment: No; I mean RemoteFX was depreciated. RDP was not

Answer (score 0):

The most definitive list I was able to find is on Wikipedia, related to the history of the RDP protocol, and inferring support based on the version of RDP included.

[Microsoft RDP protocol at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol#History)

RDP RemoteFX USB redirection was introduced in RDP v7.1 (with Windows 7 SP1), but I'm not sure if RDP v7.1 supports USB redirection in Virtual Desktops (VDI) and physical hosts.

If RDP v7.1 supports USB redirection in physical hosts, then all client Windows editions that allow RDP hosting with RDP v7.1 or newer should be able to support RemoteFX USB redirection. i.e.) Windows 7 SP1 or newer support RemoteFX USB redirection.

If only RDP v8.1 or newer upports USB redirection in physical hosts, then all client Windows editions that allow RDP hosting with RDP v8.1 or newer should be able to support RemoteFX USB redirection. i.e.) Windows 8.1 or newer support RemoteFX USB redirection.

Windows Home editions cannot host RDP sessions. See:
[Remote Desktop - Allow access to your PC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-allow-access)

Windows Server editions can host RDP sessions, but in order to use USB redirection to a Windows Server, the "Remote Desktop Session Host" role must be added, and corresponding setup. Best reference I can find, see:
[USB redirection (remoteFX) working on win10, not on server 2016](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e557cd73-32b3-4b66-93c2-62aa42df41a4/usb-redirection-remotefx-working-on-win10-not-on-server-2016?forum=winserverTS)

In the case where Windows Server is being used to host virtual desktops (VDI deployment) with Remote Desktop Services, the virtual hosts must use Windows Enterprise editions in order for RemoteFX USB redirection to the virtual desktop to work.
See: [VDI deployment – supported guest OSes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-supported-config#vdi-deployment--supported-guest-oses)

Unrelated to USB redirection, but related to more modern RemoteFX features such as:

- Remote Desktop Session Host (RDSH) support of hardware GPU
- RDSH H.264/AVC hardware encoding
- Single sign-on

Microsoft has this information:
[Supported configurations for Remote Desktop Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-supported-config)

Further reference: 
[Introducing Microsoft RemoteFX USB Redirection: Part 1](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/enterprise-mobility-security/introducing-microsoft-remotefx-usb-redirection-part-1/ba-p/247035)